# Installation of GeoDjango on Windows generates error

Tags: python, django, installation, geodjango

I am following this paper

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/install/

but it prints an error message:

```
raise improperlyconfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.improperlyconfigured:'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend.
try using 'django.db.backends.XXX',where XXX is one of:
'mysql','oracle','postgresql','sqlite3'
error was:cannot import name 'GDALRaster'
```

my **settings.py**

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'world',
]

    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
         'NAME': 'testdb',
         'USER': 'postgres',
    },
}
```

> python version 3.5 
>   django 1.10.6 
>   psycopg2 2.7

*Order of install*

> 1.python 
>   2.postgreSQL 
>   3.postGIS 
>   4.psycopg2 
>   5.OSGeo4W 
>   6.Modify Windows environment 
>   7.django

Please help me and thanx.

Comment: This is [a problem in Django 1.8 and 1.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574472/django-migrations-says-database-backend-isnt-available). Not the best solution, but can you downgrade to 1.9?

Comment: have you installed postgis extension for postgres in your database?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863476/configuring-a-postgresql-postgis-database